# Assign ranking to IPs based on frequency, within rolling windows

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rank, dense-rank

Within each ID, I'm trying to rank each IP based on how often they show up within the last 3 months. For example, in the table below, the IP 98.28.88.148 should have a ranking of 1 because they showed up the most within the last 3 months. IP 166.194.154.19 should have rank of 2, and IP 64.227.19.120 should have rank of 3 since it's least frequent. If 2 IPs show up the same number of times, they should be assigned the same Rank.

| ID | Login_TS_Three_Months_Prior | Login_TS | IP | Count_of_Logins_Three_Months_Prior |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2023-08-04T13:40:08.512Z | 2023-11-02T13:40:08.512Z | 64.227.19.120 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2023-08-04T14:35:46.717Z | 2023-11-02T14:35:46.717Z | 64.227.19.120 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2023-08-06T00:56:25.895Z | 2023-11-04T00:56:25.895Z | 98.28.88.148 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2023-08-10T15:50:21.845Z | 2023-11-08T15:50:21.845Z | 98.28.88.148 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2023-08-11T17:07:28.623Z | 2023-11-09T17:07:28.623Z | 98.28.88.148 | 2 |
| 1234 | 2023-08-12T16:52:18.59Z | 2023-11-10T16:52:18.59Z | 98.28.88.148 | 3 |
| 1234 | 2023-08-18T23:17:12.471Z | 2023-11-16T23:17:12.471Z | 166.194.154.19 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2023-08-22T20:42:57.979Z | 2023-11-20T20:42:57.979Z | 166.194.154.19 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2023-08-25T22:36:52.638Z | 2023-11-23T22:36:52.638Z | 166.194.154.19 | 2 |

The ideal output should look like this:

| ID | Login_TS_Three_Months_Prior | Login_TS | IP | Count_of_Logins_Three_Months_Prior | IP_Ranking |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2023-08-04T13:40:08.512Z | 2023-11-02T13:40:08.512Z | 64.227.19.120 | 0 | 3 |
| 1234 | 2023-08-04T14:35:46.717Z | 2023-11-02T14:35:46.717Z | 64.227.19.120 | 1 | 3 |
| 1234 | 2023-08-06T00:56:25.895Z | 2023-11-04T00:56:25.895Z | 98.28.88.148 | 0 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2023-08-10T15:50:21.845Z | 2023-11-08T15:50:21.845Z | 98.28.88.148 | 1 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2023-08-11T17:07:28.623Z | 2023-11-09T17:07:28.623Z | 98.28.88.148 | 2 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2023-08-12T16:52:18.59Z | 2023-11-10T16:52:18.59Z | 98.28.88.148 | 3 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2023-08-18T23:17:12.471Z | 2023-11-16T23:17:12.471Z | 166.194.154.19 | 0 | 2 |
| 1234 | 2023-08-22T20:42:57.979Z | 2023-11-20T20:42:57.979Z | 166.194.154.19 | 1 | 2 |
| 1234 | 2023-08-25T22:36:52.638Z | 2023-11-23T22:36:52.638Z | 166.194.154.19 | 2 | 2 |

Comment: Please provide some sample data and schemas as DDL so that others can easily test their solutions for suitability with your data. Can you also provide a bit of clarity on how the tag [tag:snowflake-schema] is relevant?

Comment: @esqew, I use Snowflake database but you're correct I don't think it matters much so I had removed that tag. I posted sample data in images, but not sure if everyone can see. I can update to use tables.

Comment: I think it does matter actually, although [tag:snowflake-schema] doesn't correspond with the data analysis platform called Snowflake. I've edited the correct tag for you to attract the attention of others also having experience with the platform.

Comment: As far as your data is concerned, images aren't copy/pasteable into local environments for testing and troubleshooting - it's recommended to include DDL statements so that others can create the tables with the sample data. Some people also access from environments where Imgur is blocked for one reason or another.

Comment: Ranking IPs based on Count_of_Logins_Three_Months_Prior would give  different result for different values of Count_of_Logins_Three_Months_Prior; are you meaning to say: 'find the max of Count_of_Logins_Three_Months_Prior for each IP in each ID, and then Rank them'?

Comment: @tinazmu I want to get the IP rank based on last 3 months from current Login_TS. For example, at the bottom of the table the Login_TS is `2023-11-23T22:36:52.638Z`. Since 3 months before that is `2023-08-25T22:36:52.638Z`, and IP 98.28.88.148 appeared the most since 2023-08-25, it should receive rank of 1. IP 166.194.154.19 has rank of 2 since it's the 2nd most frequent IP since 2023-08-25.

Comment: so you really want in a time sorted sense the 3mth window to be the current row, thus for some data, all rows could be ranked 1, if at each time period, the current rows count was +! of all the others (which could happen with low count sparse data..)... and the value of this meaningless data would be?

Comment: That's correct @SimeonPilgrim. What I'm trying to figure out is whether each IP is the most common IP within last 3 months, 2nd most common IP, 3rd most common, etc., given the Login_TS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if we get your data via a CTE, only keeping the id, timestamp, & ip address (and adding second batch with a draw in it):

```
with question_data as (
    select 
        $1 as id
        ,try_to_timestamp_ntz($2, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff"Z"') as login_ts
        ,$3 as ip
    from values
    (1234, '2023-11-02T13:40:08.512Z', '64.227.19.120'),
    (1234, '2023-11-02T14:35:46.717Z', '64.227.19.120'),
    (1234, '2023-11-04T00:56:25.895Z', '98.28.88.148'),
    (1234, '2023-11-08T15:50:21.845Z', '98.28.88.148'),
    (1234, '2023-11-09T17:07:28.623Z', '98.28.88.148'),
    (1234, '2023-11-10T16:52:18.59Z', '98.28.88.148'),
    (1234, '2023-11-16T23:17:12.471Z', '166.194.154.19'),
    (1234, '2023-11-20T20:42:57.979Z', '166.194.154.19'),
    (1234, '2023-11-23T22:36:52.638Z', '166.194.154.19'),

    (1235, '2023-11-02T13:40:08.512Z', '64.227.19.120'),
    (1235, '2023-11-02T14:35:46.717Z', '64.227.19.120'),
    (1235, '2023-11-04T00:56:25.895Z', '98.28.88.148'),
    (1235, '2023-11-08T15:50:21.845Z', '98.28.88.148'),
    (1235, '2023-11-09T17:07:28.623Z', '98.28.88.148'),
    (1235, '2023-11-10T16:52:18.59Z', '98.28.88.148'),
    (1235, '2023-11-20T20:42:57.979Z', '166.194.154.19'),
    (1235, '2023-11-23T22:36:52.638Z', '166.194.154.19')
)
```

we first want to do the count (well really we might want to do the filter, but I assume you have this bit sorted, so we will can count). Using a window function form of COUNT:

```
    select *, 
        count(*)over(partition by id, ip) as ip_count
    from question_data
```

those id/ip batches counted.

[image]

now for ranking there are three forms, ROW_NUMBER, DENSE_RANK and RANK. The first gives every item it's own number, the second gives duplicates equal numbers, and increases by 1, the third gives equals the same, but the 100th RANK item will have only 100 values prior to it (this is like the Olympic's a draw for first gives 1,1,3), it sounds like what you want is the second.

Now given we are going to run this in a window function fashion again, it needs the prior window function for the count, to be at a different query layer (a sub-select), thus some code show the second/third options:

```
select d.*
    ,dense_rank() over(partition by d.id order by ip_count desc) as ip_ranking_d
    ,rank() over(partition by d.id order by ip_count desc) as ip_ranking_s
from (
    select *, 
        count(*)over(partition by id, ip) as ip_count
    from question_data
) as d
order by d.id, d.ip, d.login_ts;
```

[image]

here we see in the 1235 id batch, the two IP's with a count of 2 are 2nd equal. Now the question becomes what do you want to happen to the next count, if you want that to be 3, this method works just fine. But if you want the next number after duplicates to be 4, we need a method of allocating sparse values, and join those results.

so if the above code is what you want, then the clean form looks like:

```
select d.* exclude(ip_count)
    ,dense_rank() over(partition by d.id order by ip_count desc) as ip_ranking_d
from (
    select *, 
        count(*)over(partition by id, ip) as ip_count
    from question_data
) as d
```

but if we want the shared count, but correctly counted gaps:

```
select *
from question_data
natural join (
    select 
        id,
        ip,
        rank() over (partition by id order by ip_count desc) as ip_rank
    from (
        select         
            id,
            ip,
            count(*) as ip_count
        from question_data
        group by 1,2
    )
)
order by 1,2,3;
```

so with an extra row of data:

```
    (1235, '2023-11-23T22:36:52.638Z', '166.194.154.18')
```

the dense form allocation 3:

[image]

where-as the sparse version with the join allocates 4:

[image]

### with more time consideration:

so the last 3 months of data per row starts with this:

```
with question_data as (
    select 
        $1 as id
        ,try_to_timestamp_ntz($2, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff"Z"') as login_ts
        ,$3 as ip
    from values
    (1234, '2023-11-02T00:00:00.000Z', 'a'),
    (1234, '2023-10-02T00:00:00.000Z', 'a'),
    (1234, '2023-09-02T00:00:00.000Z', 'a'),
    (1234, '2023-08-02T00:00:00.000Z', 'a'),

    (1234, '2023-11-16T00:00:00.000Z', 'b'),
    (1234, '2023-10-16T00:00:00.000Z', 'b'),
    (1234, '2023-09-16T00:00:00.000Z', 'b'),
    (1234, '2023-08-16T00:00:00.000Z', 'b')
), enrich as (
    select *, seq8() as s
    from question_data
)
select a.*
    ,b.ip as b_ip
    ,b.s as b_s
    ,b.login_ts as b_login_ts
from enrich as a
left join enrich as b
    on a.id = b.id 
    and b.login_ts between dateadd('month', -3, a.login_ts) and a.login_ts
order by 4,6;
```

[image]

then we want count these rows:

```
), three_months as (
    select a.*
        ,b.ip as b_ip
        ,b.s as b_s
        ,b.login_ts as b_login_ts
    from enrich as a
    left join enrich as b
        on a.id = b.id 
        and b.login_ts between dateadd('month', -3, a.login_ts) and a.login_ts
)
select id, 
    login_ts, 
    ip, 
    s, -- does not seem to be needed anymore.. not sure where I was going with that
    b_ip, 
    count(*) as b_ip_count
from three_months
group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

then we want to rank those:

```
), counted as (
    select id, 
        login_ts, 
        ip, 
        s, -- s is used for the ranking partition..
        b_ip, 
        count(*) as b_ip_count
    from three_months
    group by 1,2,3,4,5
)
select *
    ,rank() over (partition by id, s order by b_ip_count desc) as sparse_rank
    ,dense_rank() over (partition by id, s order by b_ip_count desc) as dense_rank   
from counted
order by 1,4,5;
```

[image]

now we want to throw away the lines, where ip <> b_ip as those are the other ranked lines:

thus we now have the three month window from this row, ranked:

```
with question_data as (
    select 
        $1 as id
        ,try_to_timestamp_ntz($2, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff"Z"') as login_ts
        ,$3 as ip
    from values
    (1234, '2023-11-02T00:00:00.000Z', 'a'),
    (1234, '2023-10-02T00:00:00.000Z', 'a'),
    (1234, '2023-09-02T00:00:00.000Z', 'a'),
    (1234, '2023-08-02T00:00:00.000Z', 'a'),

    (1234, '2023-11-16T00:00:00.000Z', 'b'),
    (1234, '2023-10-16T00:00:00.000Z', 'b'),
    (1234, '2023-09-16T00:00:00.000Z', 'b'),
    (1234, '2023-08-16T00:00:00.000Z', 'b')
), enrich as (
    select *, seq8() as s
    from question_data
), three_months as (
    select a.*
        ,b.ip as b_ip
        ,b.s as b_s
        ,b.login_ts as b_login_ts
    from enrich as a
    left join enrich as b
        on a.id = b.id 
        and b.login_ts between dateadd('month', -3, a.login_ts) and a.login_ts
), counted as (
    select id, 
        login_ts, 
        ip, 
        s, -- s is used for the ranking partition..
        b_ip, 
        count(*) as b_ip_count
    from three_months
    group by 1,2,3,4,5
)
select c.* exclude (s, b_ip, b_ip_count)
    ,rank() over (partition by id, s order by b_ip_count desc) as sparse_rank
    ,dense_rank() over (partition by id, s order by b_ip_count desc) as dense_rank   
from counted as c
qualify ip = b_ip
order by 1,4,5;
```

giving:

[image]

Now, clearly for your data, it will not all be ones, and you still need to pick dense or sparse. But this code seem to be what you are wanting.

Comment: My understanding is this approach will do an all-time count of each IP, rather than counting the IP occurrence within the last 3 months prior to the Login_TS, which is what I needed. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct, if you want to look at 10 months of data, but have the counts only be that last 3 month for each row, and some how have those ranked same or not same then, you will need a lot more complex example data, because it seems you are mixing your messages.

Comment: what does it mean to rank a id,ip on date n-1 as ranked 4 when the day after it is rank 17th, or the day prior it is 1st. Over what domain is the ranking happening..

Comment: or another way of framing it, I assumed you would have done a `select * from data where timestamp >= dateadd('month',-3,current_date)` filter, so it's is "the last 3 months of data"

Comment: Yes @Simeon, in my query I did some joins and retrieved the last 3 months timestamp which was used to calculate the `Count_of_Logins_Three_Months_Prior`

Comment: added the rolling window method to the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Simeon! I tested and it's exactly what I needed. May I ask what role does the `seq8` function play? This is first time I see that function.

Comment: @Stanleyrr i was using it to make a simple unique id for each row, thus making the partitioning simpler. As i joined the data to itself, but really it was a proxy for  “id, ip” and i even used “id, s”, but also because ip is a sting string compares/hahses are not coolest. But that was the intent. Also this is 3 month windowing on every row, where it might make more sense to count on a whole day basis and then join to the pior 90 days worth of counts. If you have 100k of rows.